# WORDPRESS Database How to return meta value from database?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, metadata

I have in database this meta_key  `fw:ext:mm:io:primefeed`  and this meta_value `a:5:{s:4:"type";s:6:"column";s:3:"row";a:0:{}s:6:"column";a:1:{s:14:"item_thumbnail";a:2:{s:13:"attachment_id";s:2:"11";s:3:"url";s:49:"//primefeed.loc/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/01.jpg";}}s:4:"item";a:0:{}s:7:"default";a:0:{}}` 
How to return this meta value (link) `//primefeed.loc/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/01.jpg` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's [a PHP serialized array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). You can see the structure using

```
print_r( unserialize( $value ) );
```

e.g. [repl.it demo](https://repl.it/@RupW/so59603911)

Inside WordPress, you can do

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta($post_id, "fw:ext:mm:io:primefeed", true);
$url = $meta_value["column"]["item_thumbnail"]["url"];
```

where get_post_meta does both the database fetch and unserialize.

Comment: thx, but nothing happen, i tried to echo $url, and it returns nothing..

Comment: Oh :-/ It does work for the example you gave me - see the repl.it link. What is this in WordPress? I don't recognise that structure or meta_key.